# Pass input to terminal automatically?

Tags: linux, command-line, amazon-web-services, terminal

I want to enter "yes" as a input when to "yes/no" automatically prompt on the screen instead of manually, here is the script

```
ansible-playbook -i hostvnc.ini vnc.yml --user=ubuntu --private-key=rampvnc.pem --extra-vars="dns=ec2-54-205-170-165.compute-1.amazonaws.com"
```

the dns option that I am passing on is actually generated dynamically. During the execution of this script here that very prompt

```
PLAY [vnc] ******************************************************************** 

GATHERING FACTS *************************************************************** 
The authenticity of host 'ec2-54-205-170-165.compute-1.amazonaws.com (54.205.170.165)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is 31:7f:a1:f0:18:73:f1:6d:b9:dc:16:25:4a:4f:40:5f.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

How can I enter "yes" as a input ?, I have tried this option but no success

ansible-playbook -i hostvnc.ini vnc.yml --user=ubuntu --private-key=rampvnc.pem --extra-vars="dns=ec2-54-205-170-165.compute-1.amazonaws.com" | echo "yes"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

what about `yes | your_command`.

or better yet add this line to your 
~/.ssh/config

```
StrictHostKeyChecking no
```

Comment: Thanks StrictHostKeyChecking no option has done the trick and guys don't forget to uncoment the line and I have fine mine ssh/config at this path "/etc/ssh/config"

Comment: that file is the global setting for all users, ~/.ssh/config has the user's settings.